# Butter Knife syncing problems

Tags: android, butterknife

Hi been having problems with getting butter knife setup. not sure where im going wrong as if tried multiple solutions but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

below is the build project level

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'

}
```

the module level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cormac.gymappproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
                 }
              }
         }

    dependencies {
          implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
          implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
          implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-
    layout:1.0.2'
          testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
           androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
           androidTestImplementation 
        'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
       compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
       annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
       }
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csnSd.png

Comment: Change `compile` to `implementation` now that you're using the latest version of Gradle

Comment: Also, what problems? Are you seeing any error messages with your Gradle sync or build?

Comment: its a sync issue i have attached a screenshot of the problem

Comment: And none of those suggestions work?

Comment: unfortunately not